# Can I use multiple fonts at the same time?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

I want to do do the same thing [this guy accomplished in Atom.](https://medium.com/@docodemore/an-alternative-to-operator-mono-font-6e5d040e1c7e#.hzuoabqwt) I want to use one font for comments, and another for my actual code.

Is this possible in WebStorm? I've fiddled with my settings, but I can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently it's not possible.

The only moments when IDE can use more than one font in Editor area are:

1. When primary font does not have glyph for specific character -- then IDE will look up in secondary/fallback font
2. When you choose to use font ligatures (displaying specific character sequences as one custom symbol)

---

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-161729 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

Partially related tickets:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146471
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-109338
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-92825